# Detect [Enter] key in bat file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I give my users a couple of options, then wait for their input.  In my testing when I hit the [Enter] key with putting in any selection the program will crash and burn.  It gives me the error "( was unexpected at this time."  How can I detect if user solely presses the [Enter] key?

Here's what I have.

```
:pickClient
set clientNum=
cls
echo.
echo  Pick a Client
echo.
echo.
echo    1. Client 1
echo.
echo    2. Client 2
echo.
echo.
echo   [E] - EXIT
echo.
set /p clientNum=Input selection.  

if %clientNum%==1 (

     set client=client1Name

) else if %clientNum%==2 (

     set client=client2Name

) else if /i %clientNum%==E (

     GOTO goAway

) else if %clientNum%==" " (

     GOTO pickClient

) else (

     GOTO pickClient

)
```

Comment: Feel free to `accept` the answer of `ths` - see the `tour` in the help menu.

Comment: you can shorten your program by using `if` with the `/i` parameter to ignore capitalization.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan! I appreciate your input!  I didn't know that was available.  I've updated my code to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you just press enter, the variable is empty and your comparisons

```
if %clientNum%==1 (
```

become

```
if ==1 (
```

which is illegal. to prevent problems like this, or spaces in variable values, it is prudent to always surround the variables and values in the `if` with quotes:

```
if "%clientNum%"=="1" (
```

then becomes

```
if ""=="1" (
```

which is a valid statement.

Comment: Thank you @ths for your help!  I didn't know about the quotes.  I'm pretty new to batching, so any help is GREATLY appreciated.  I'll make the edits to my batch.

Comment: To add to this, if I had ` IF "%clientNum%"=="" ` would there be a need to check if the variable is defined or not?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!  Here's what I did.

```
set clientNum=
cls
echo.
echo  Pick a Client
echo.
echo.
echo    1. Client 1
echo.
echo    2. Client 2
echo.
echo.
echo   [E] - EXIT
echo.
set /p clientNum=Input selection.  

IF NOT DEFINED clientNum GOTO pickClient  <---I added this line of code. *****

if %clientNum%==1 (

     set client=client1Name

) else if %clientNum%==2 (

     set client=client2Name

) else if /i %clientNum%==E (

     GOTO goAway

) else if %clientNum%==" " (

     GOTO pickClient

) else (

     GOTO pickClient

)
```

UPDATE:

Thanks to @ths's helpful input, I've found that I should start using quotes when testing variables. Through my own testing I found that the following works just as well as testing for DEFINED.

```
set clientNum=
cls
echo.
echo  Pick a Client
echo.
echo.
echo    1. Client 1
echo.
echo    2. Client 2
echo.
echo.
echo    [E] - EXIT
echo.
set /p clientNum=Input selection.  

if "%clientNum%"=="1" (

     set client=client1Name

) else if "%clientNum%"=="2" (

     set client=client2Name

) else if /i "%clientNum%"=="E" (

     GOTO goAway

) else if "%clientNum%"==" " (

     GOTO pickClient

) else if "%clientNum%"=="" (

     GOTO pickClient

) else (

     GOTO pickClient

)
```

NOTE the quotes.  Give some love to ths by up-voting his input.  I'm greatly appreciative of it.